# Why does a Go package show up as undefined?

Tags: rest, go, package

I'm having trouble understanding what the issue is with my code below. The Visual Studio Code compiler is giving me errors such as the following because the package "util" is undefined.

```
'Error' message: 'undefined: util.GetPortAndURL
```

I'm placing the following at the top of my util.go file

```
package util
```

I'm also importing the package myproj/util in my handlers.go file, which is the one calling the below code in its init method.

```
file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./creds.json")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("File error: %v\n", err)
    // use a better error pattern here
}
json.Unmarshal(file, &oathCred)
port, url := util.GetPortAndURL() <-------- Here
if (port != nil) && (url != nil) {
    oathConf = &oauth2.Config{
        ClientID:     oathCred.ClientID,
        ClientSecret: oathCred.ClientSecret,
        RedirectURL:  url + ":" + string(port) + "/auth",
        Scopes: []string{
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", // You have to select your own scope from here -> https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#google_sign-in
        },
        Endpoint: google.Endpoint,
    }
}
```

The getPortAndURL() function is in util.go and is as follows

```
// GetPortandURL returns the URL and Port currently used
/*
'
This function should be used to set the port and url for the program until a
set function is created.
'
*/
func GetPortandURL() (int, string) {
    port := 8080
    url := "http://127.0.0.1"
    return port, url
}
```

My GOPATH is C:\Users\Me\Documents\code\go

The file structure is as follows

```
go/src/
└── myproj
    ├── handlers
    ├── main
    └── util
```

Comment: Paste the complete error into the question. And also the location of your myproj folder inside of your GOPATH

Comment: It's saying that GetPortAndURL is undefined. Have you defined that?

Comment: Yes, I've defined it as a function in util.go. I've edited my question to reflect the method as well.

Comment: If the code here is the same as in your project the issue is that the function is called `GetPortandURL` in package util but you are calling function `GetPortAndURL` with a capital `A`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Why did go alert me that "util in util.GetPortAndURL is undefined" instead of "GetPortandURL in util.GetPortAndURL is undefined"?

Comment: @TylerCheek The error as you put it in the question is correct. It doesn't says 'package util' is undefined, it says 'undefined: util.GetPortAndURL' that is the function `GetPortAndURL` in package `util`. Otherwise it would be unclear to which function it is referring as 2 packages can have a function with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Call it as `port, url := GetPortAndURL()`. I don't believe it needs the "util." package prefix if util.go (the definition) is in the same package.